Turbolink is loading before getting the session token from the Shopify App Bridge
I am implementing session token in our existing shopify app, It is a multi page application so I am using turbolink (suggested by shopify docs).
See the below code that I'm using for generating Session Token.
For using Shopify Session Token I have to add Authorization token with every URL of my application.
I'm not getting session token for first page.
Issue:- First page is loading before getting session token from Shopify App Bridge
Here is the code that I'm using...
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@shopify/app-bridge@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@shopify/app-bridge-utils"></script>

<script type="module">
 var host = "<?= \Session::get('host') ?>";

 const SESSION_TOKEN_REFRESH_INTERVAL = 2000;

 function retrieveToken(app) {

  window['app-bridge-utils'].getSessionToken(app).then(token => {
    window.sessionToken = token;
  });
}

 document.addEventListener("turbolinks:request-start", function(event) {

 retrieveToken(app);

var xhr = event.data.xhr;
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + window.sessionToken);
});

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:render", function() {
$("form, a[data-method=delete]").on("ajax:beforeSend", function(event) {
  const xhr = event.detail[0];
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + window.sessionToken);
});
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
var data = document.getElementById("shopify-app-init").dataset;
var AppBridge = window["app-bridge"];
var createApp = AppBridge.default;
window.app = createApp({
  apiKey: '<?= env('App_Client_Id'); ?>',
  host: host,
});

var actions = AppBridge.actions;
var TitleBar = actions.TitleBar;
TitleBar.create(app, {
  title: data.page,
});

// Wait for a session token before trying to load an authenticated page
await retrieveToken(app);

// Keep retrieving a session token periodically
keepRetrievingToken(app);

// Redirect to the requested page when DOM loads
var isInitialRedirect = true;
redirectThroughTurbolinks(isInitialRedirect);

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function(event) {
  redirectThroughTurbolinks();
});

// Helper functions
function redirectThroughTurbolinks(isInitialRedirect = false) {
  var data = document.getElementById("shopify-app-init").dataset;
  var validLoadPath = data && data.loadPath;
  var shouldRedirect = false;

  switch (isInitialRedirect) {
    case true:
      shouldRedirect = validLoadPath;
      break;
    case false:
      shouldRedirect = validLoadPath && data.loadPath !== "<?= url("/shopify/dashboard") ?>"; // Replace with the app's home_path
      break;
  }

  if (shouldRedirect) Turbolinks.visit(data.loadPath);
}
function keepRetrievingToken(app) {
  setInterval(() => {
    retrieveToken(app);
  }, SESSION_TOKEN_REFRESH_INTERVAL);
}
});
</script>

Problem: The "turbolinks:request-start" event is running before "DOMContentLoaded" event, due to this behaviour, token is not added on the first request's header.
Does this is expected behaviour? or I'm doing this in wrong way?
